# Running sidekiq in rails 4 with redis and clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have redis-server running on Linux Mint 17 on port 6379. I am using the following clockwork file in `lib/clock.rb` to run a cron task using sidekiq:

```
require 'clockwork'

require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork
  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every(5.seconds, 'COLLECT FEEDS ---------') do
    FeedUpdater.perform_async()
  end
end
```

The sidekiq task is defined as follows:

```
class FeedUpdater
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    puts 'Doing hard work'
  end
end
```

However, when I run `bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb` I get the following output:

```
I, [2014-11-15T14:00:43.888627 #27822]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [ COLLECT FEEDS --------- ]
I, [2014-11-15T14:00:43.888700 #27822]  INFO -- : Triggering 'COLLECT FEEDS ---------'
2014-11-15T19:00:43Z 27822 TID-2ipeg INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {}
I, [2014-11-15T14:00:48.891139 #27822]  INFO -- : Triggering 'COLLECT FEEDS ---------'
I, [2014-11-15T14:00:53.893416 #27822]  INFO -- : Triggering 'COLLECT FEEDS ---------'
```

I expect the output to include the task (simple print statement).

My Gemfile looks like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'feedjira'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.1.4'
gem 'clockwork', '~> 0.7.7'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start sidekiq worker in separate shell. Also it's better to configure redis for sidekiq if not yet (set db or namespace)

Comment: If you don't need separate worker, you can use `celluloid` gem, it powers sidekiq, but doesn't require redis.